# Use explicit namespace with infix operator

Tags: r, dplyr

The `dplyr` R package has the `%>%` operator, which is a custom infix operator. If one attaches the namespace with `library(dplyr)` one can use this operator. In library code the `library(dplyr)` at the top of the file has no effect because the environment after executing the source code is stored; loaded packages have no effect on that.

So in order to use this in my library, I have these options:

1. Just use `library(dplyr)` at the beginning of each function.
2. Do not use the infix operator and rather write the functions with out the “pipe” operator `%>%`.
3. Try to use `dplyr::%>%`.

The last option is what I want to do, but I cannot seem to get the syntax right. I have tried

```
dplyr::%>%
```

and get parsing errors. Also

```
dplyr::`%>%`
```

does not work. And

```
`dplyr::%>%`
```

does not work either. I don't think that there is any other way to place the backticks. Is this something that is possible in R or do I just have to use option 1 or 2?

Comment: I think the pipe actually originates in `magrittr`, and `dplyr` imports it. If you use `usethis` for development, there's a function `use_pipe` that sets up importing the pipe operator for you. General guidance is to *not* load libraries within your package's code

Comment: camille's right, `dplyr` imports and re-exports the pipe, see the top of [this file](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/utils.r).

Comment: Following up on what they said, import and reexport the pipe from magrittr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just import the pipe operator, by adding a line like

```
importFrom(magrittr, "%>%")
```

in your `NAMESPACE` file, or if you're using `roxygen2`, putting

```
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
```

into one of your `.R` files to do the same thing.

You may or may not want to export it as well.  Do export it with a line like

```
export("%>%")
```

in your `NAMESPACE` file or with `roxygen2`

```
#' @export
magrittr::`%>%`
```

if you want your users to use the pipe operator when they are using your package.  Don't export it if you only need it to be available internally.